# C++ Do I have memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in,hhh& hh){

    double *arr,*temp;
    int i=0;
    char c;
    c=in.peek();
    while(c!='\n'){
        if(i>=1){
            temp=new double[++i];
            for(int j=0;j<i-1;j++){
                temp[j]=arr[j];
            }
            arr=temp;
        }
        else {
            arr=new double[++i];
        }
        in>>arr[i-1];
        c=in.peek();
    }
    hh.set(arr,i);
    delete [] arr;
    return in;
}
```

Do I have memory leak? I'm trying to figure out if i have but I'm not sure about that, thanks for your help.

Comment: You do. Before writing `arr = temp;`, first you have to `delete [] arr;`. (Also, initialize `temp` and `arr` to `nullptr` so that you can safely `delete []` them for the first time.)

Comment: Learn how to use `std::vector<double>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have.

when you create the bigger array, you don't delete the smaller one.

```
double* arr = 0;
int size = 0;
for (char c = in.peek(); c != '\n'; c = in.peek()) {
    double* temp = new double[++size];
    // memcpy(temp, arr, (size - 1) * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i != size - 1; ++i){
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
    arr = temp;
    in >> arr[i-1];
}
```

or better, use std::vector<double> arr;

```
std::vector<double> arr;
for (char c = in.peek(); c != '\n'; c = in.peek()) {
    double d;
    in >> d;
    arr.push_back(d);
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != size - 1; ++i)` goes wrong when size = 0. Use `i < size` instead!

Comment: why you commented // memcpy(temp, arr, (size - 1) * sizeof(double));?

Comment: @MatsPetersson size is incremented before, and cannot be 0

Comment: @MikeL I let it as an alternative to the next loop which copy elements, so use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. In the assignment `arr=temp;` you overwrite the old pointer without freeing it. I would recommend not using raw pointers. Instead use `std::unique_ptr< double[] >` to wrap your pointers. It will guarantee that you won't leak.

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr< double[] > arr, temp;

arr.reset( new double[++i] ); // in C++14 you would use std::make_unique instead
```

Comment: So when I point arr=temp, then delete [] arr, temp is getting deleted because arr is pointed to temp, Is that correct?

Comment: @MikeL pretty much, yes